# How would I convert a string with a two digit date to the correct date with Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

If you run any kind of a query within Spark SQL, it will convert dates to future dates.  Basically, anything that you would logically think is going to be based in the past gets converted into a future date.

For instance, if you do a simple statement like the following:

`select to_date('1/1/94', 'm/d/yy')`

You will get: **2094-01-01**

Is there an easy way, aside from post processing (subtracting 100 years from anything in the future) to logically handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `m` means minutes and not month. You need to use `M` for months. Second of all, `94` is interpreted as `2094` because spark 3.x uses a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and this is the default behavior of this class. Spark 2.X however used to use a [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) that interpreted 94 as 1994. If you want to use the legacy time formatting, you can set `spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy` to `LEGACY`:

```scala
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")
spark.sql("select to_date('2/10/94', 'M/d/yy') as date").show
```

```
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|1994-02-10|
+----------+
```

Comment: Outstanding - I'll give that a shot and see how it goes.